# vnc server for headless Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vnc

So, i've had issues with vnc4server, the s and tab keys are both borked, and want to try something else. I've tried x11vnc, but that requires an actual display connected to the system. Are there any other vnc programs i could try out?

Comment: please remove x11vnc kind of things you have already installed before proceeding... sudo apt-get purge x11vnc

Comment: yup, already did.

Comment: The numeric keypad also has problems in vnc4server but of course this is surmountable with the top row digit keys. If this link is relevant https://www.mail-archive.com/vnc-list@realvnc.com/msg14260.html then it appears that there has been no fix in 15 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the things worked for me.. (original source http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04 )

do these

(1) run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

(2)run `sudo apt-get install gnome-core xfce4 vnc4server`

(3)then add users (vncserver/unix)

```
sudo adduser test1
```

(you will have to fill details afterwards for the user, I have added 3 users (test1, test2, test3 etc for vnc server)

(4)Then you have to switch users one by one and run vncserver and add password for vncuser login ***(I have three vnc users, so that i had to repeat this for all three user test 1, test2, test3)***

```
su - test1
```

then run

```
vncserver
```

out put will be like this prompting for a vnc password..

```
You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password:
Verify:

xauth:  file /home/test1/.Xauthority does not exist
New 'server1:1 (test1)' desktop is server1:1
Creating default startup script /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/test1/.vnc/server1:1.log
```

(5) Important : you will have to replace /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup content with below **(Else you will not get the desktop, instead you will stuck with blank screen without user interfaces or menus )**

```
vim /home/test1/.vnc/xstartup
```

and add

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

(6) startup script for the vncserver was created using ["Further I will make the startup script for the vncserver like this"](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04) section of [this tute](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04)

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/vncserver
```

and add below content..

```
#!/bin/bash

unset VNCSERVERARGS
VNCSERVERS=""
[ -f /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf ] && . /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
prog=$"VNC server"
start() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
 ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1
 RETVAL=0
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 DISP="${display%%:*}"
 export VNCUSERARGS="${VNCSERVERARGS[${DISP}]}"
 su ${USER} -c "cd ~${USER} && [ -f .vnc/passwd ] && vncserver :${DISP} ${VNCUSERARGS}"
 fi
 done
}
stop() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Shutting down VNCServer: "
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 su ${USER} -c "vncserver -kill :${display%%:*}" >/dev/null 2>&1
 fi
 done
 echo -e "\n"
 echo "VNCServer Stopped"
}
case "$1" in
start)
start $@
;;
stop)
stop $@
;;
restart|reload)
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
;;
condrestart)
if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/vncserver ]; then
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
fi
;;
status)
status Xvnc
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
exit 1
esac
```

to make it an executable run the following..

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver
```

(7) To make vnc desktop sessions allocated for users at start up automatically, create following script in /etc/vncserver

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/vncserver
sudo vim /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
```

add this in vncservers.conf (this is because i have my users as test1, test2, test3 change it according to )

```
VNCSERVERS="3:test3 2:test2 1:test1"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

(8) Then run

```
sudo `update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99`
```

(9) reboot server (you are almost done by now) step 10 and the rest is how to login part

(10)download http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/

enter servername/ipaddress and session id 
for example my server is 172.16.70.17 and if i use 172.16.70.17:2 it will login to test2 user desktop.. and 172.16.70.17:3 will login to test3 user desktop like wise

make sure encryption to be selected "Prefer off"

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

Then you can access your desktop and applications in this manner..

[image: pic]

Comment: if xface is not ok, you have to find a different solution....  above is merely answering your initial question only "I've tried x11vnc, but that requires an actual display connected to the system. Are there any other vnc programs i could try out?"

Comment: after **sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99** I see `insserv: warning: script 'vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides`

Comment: I have also received this warning "insserv: warning: script 'vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides", yet its a warning, I could not fix it. But everything is working in spite of the warning

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in your `/etc/init.d/vncserver` file and then the errors about not having LSB Headers will be gone.

```
\#\#\# BEGIN INIT INFO

\# Provides:          vnc4server

\# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network

\# Required-Stop:     $local_fs

\# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5

\# Default-Stop:      0 1 6

\# Short-Description: vnc4server

\# Description:       VNC4 Server as a startup daemon

\#\#\# END INIT INFO
```