# Cannot connect to x11vnc server before login

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have installed x11vnc on ubuntu 15.10. Based on:

[Remmina cannot perform VNC remote desktop session before user logs in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647039/remmina-cannot-perform-vnc-remote-desktop-session-before-user-logs-in)

I have created a new file: **/etc/init/x11vnc.conf** on **MYSERVER** containing:

```
start on login-session-start
script
x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -loop -forever -safer -shared -ultrafilexfer -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /home/moore/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -http -users moore -nowireframe
end script
```

I have now rebooted **MYSERVER** and am trying to RDP to it from another ubuntu machine using Remmina:

[image]

But I just get:

[image]

I also tried following this guide:

http://seb.so/vnc-from-boot-without-logging-in-ubuntu-lubuntu-xubuntu-and-mint-lmde/

same result.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested below I have now tried to run:

```
x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -loop -forever -safer -shared -ultrafilexfer -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /home/moore/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -http -users moore -nowireframe
```

from a terminal where I first SSH'ed to the server. It gave me this error:

```
...disabling -bg in -loop mode error opening logfile: /var/log/x11vnc.log open: Permission denied
```

But if I then do it as root from the same terminal it now works! But why does it not do that automatically when the machine is rebooted?

Notice when I did the small manual test above as root the file **/var/log/x11vnc.log** was created so it now exists with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root              root     12640 Feb 19 00:26 x11vnc.log
```

But it still fails to  start automatically on boot. It seems that whatever user is running the script on boot is NOT root.

**UPDATE2:**

The updated below answer solved the problem - that addresses the issue in Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: In remmina it is important to configure with correct color depth. Connection crashed with broken pipe in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only three things I can think of that might be preventing you from connecting:

1. Do you have a firewall in place? Have you unblock access to port 5903? You can do that using UFW which is a GUI for your firewall in Ubuntu.
2. Are you trying to access the server from outside your network? In that case you also have to forward the 5903 port on your router to access the VNC server (in addition to point 1). If you are getting this error when connecting from the same network, ignore this option but keep it in mind when connecting from outside the network.
3. Last one, which is silly but I wanted to cover my bases. Are you trying to connect from the same computer? I don't think x11vnc allows for loopback connections, so always try use a different computer when testing (or your phone). EDIT: after testing, it works with at least Remmina using the 192.168... local address.

I also use x11vnc server on my computer, but the difference is that only the localhost can access it. I also run an SSH server, that way I have a way more secure connection, and once a user ssh to your computer, they can connect to the VNC server as a localhost.

I hope this helps

**EDIT**

After trableshooting, the problem is that Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't have upstart so x11vnc will never run on boot.
Instead, you have to create a service and make it available at boot. Here's what to do:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

Insert this into the file:

```
[Unit]
Description="x11vnc"
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess -loop -forever -safer -shared -ultrafilexfer -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /home/moore/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -http -users moore -nowireframe
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you can start the service with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start x11vnc
```

And to make the service start on boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable x11vnc
```

This solution was previously posted by ***babelmonk*** [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/676978/6211)

Comment: No to all 3. Any ideas where I can find the log for when the script /etc/init/x11vnc.conf is executed? This file: /var/log/x11vnc.log does not even exist so I suspect that /etc/init/x11vnc.conf  has never been executed.

Comment: if the command is not being executed, can you run the command directly from the command line? (x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -loop -forever -safer -shared -ultrafilexfer -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /home/moore/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -http -users moore -nowireframe)
See if you get any errors and report back

Comment: Hm when I do that from a SSH session to the server before I have logged in to it I get:  "disabling -bg in -loop mode
error opening logfile: /var/log/x11vnc.log
open: Permission denied"   so something is not right

Comment: ok, so now we know what the problem is. Please try creating the file /var/log/x11vnc.log manually, and make sure that its ownership is to root. Post back if it works an if so I'll edit the response to reflect that and have it as an accepted answer

Comment: That file was created during my manual test and is owned by root, see edited pot above. But it still does not work/x11vnc is not started on boot before login.  I still have to SSH manually to the server and as root run the command line to make it work.

Comment: I know what the problem is, Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't have upstart, so I'm updating this answer with the solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35956/discussion-between-felipe-and-u123).