# gnome-remote-desktop as a service

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, 21.10

I am using the built-in VNC server, which I believe is called `gnome-remote-desktop` and is enabled using GNOME Settings -> Sharing -> Screen sharing.

I enabled it on my desktop PC and can connect successfully to it from my laptop PC (the idea behind this is to make it easier to use a single keyboard and screen without having to press button to switch between the two).

However, in order to connect to it, I need to be logged in on the desktop PC. Can I run this server as a service so that I can connect to my PC from my laptop and *then* log in?

(This question is similar to [this one from 2015](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647039/remmina-cannot-perform-vnc-remote-desktop-session-before-user-logs-in) but this question is about `gnome-remote-desktop` whereas the other question was about the now-discontinued `vino`. Also, in the 6 years that have passed, there may be better solutions.)