# Remote Desktop over WAN

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, ssh, remote-desktop

I've got a Ubuntu server and an Ubuntu desktop, with about 4-40ms of latency (they are in 2 different buildings, connected via a fiber ring) between them. Both are running 14.04.3, of the respective server and desktop flavors.

Other than SSH X forwarding (which can't handle the 4-40ms latency swing very well), what are my options for connecting to a specific application? Is there a way to run a headless xserver on the server, and then do VNC or something to just *that* specific application (firefox) on the headless xserver?

Comment: There will be a 500 rep bounty going up on this for a working answer!

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/a/621321/158442?

Comment: @muru That looks like it's setting up a full desktop environment... i just want one application/minimal setup.

Comment: That's because the `~/.vnc/xstartup` described runs `startxfce4`. You could just run `firefox` instead.